# Как управлять директивой из контроллера? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Уважаемые коллеги, подскажите, какая есть лучшая практика для управления директивой извне? Допустим у меня есть элемент DOM, логика которого описана в директиве, поведение которого управляется функциями внутри директивы. Мне нужно создать API для управления директивой извне, то есть возможность запускать эти функции из контроллера. Как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: никак директива должна быть независима, она может общаться с _другими директивами_ через контроллеры директив, либо слушать/слать события либо через биндинги, но напрямую доступа к директиве из контроллера нет

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В таком случае, как заставить директиву слушать события в контроллере?

Comment: с помощью стандартного механизма: [scope.$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Это помогло

Comment: @Grundy Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, готово

Answer (score 1):

Директива должна быть независима, она может общаться

- с другими директивами через контроллеры директив, [справка](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate),
- слушать/слать события [scope.$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24on),
- через биндинги, когда данные передаваемые в директиву меняются в том месте откуда передаются

Но напрямую доступа к директиве из контроллера нет